# Add a Generic List/Enumerable DataRow to DataTable?

Tags: c#, generics, datatable

I am trying to write a function which takes generic List/Enumerable and add DataRow to existing DataTable but only for Custom Columns.

```
public void AddGridRow<T>(IEnumerable<T> rowData, params String[] columnNames)
{
  HashSet<String> columnsHashSet = new HashSet<String>(columnNames);

  PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
  foreach (T item in rowData)
  {
      foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
      {
         foreach (DataColumn column in _dataGridTable.Columns)
         {
             DataRow newRow = _dataGridTable.NewRow();
             if (columnsHashSet.Contains(prop.Name))
             {
                 newRow[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                 _dataGridTable.Rows.Add(newRow); // _dataGridTable is my existing DataTable
                break;
             }
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Now the problem is it is not behaving correctly, lets say I have to add 1 row in 4 columns (columnNames), it is adding the 1 Row per columns. Also there are far many foreach loops.
How can I correct this and if possible optimize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the "_dataGridTable.Rows.Add(newRow);"  line outside of the inner foreach loop:

```
foreach (T item in rowData)
  {
      foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
      {
         DataRow newRow = _dataGridTable.NewRow();
         foreach (DataColumn column in _dataGridTable.Columns)
         {
             if (columnsHashSet.Contains(prop.Name))
             {
                 newRow[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                break;
             }
          }
       }
      _dataGridTable.Rows.Add(newRow); // _dataGridTable is my existing DataTable
   }
```

Comment: Can you Provide me the code for it since If I remove the  _dataGridTable.Rows.Add(newRow); from innermost forloop , It adds columnNames.Count Items per row.

Comment: Thanks, It is working as desired now, However you need to take    DataRow newRow = _dataGridTable.NewRow(); to the outer scope